# Excel-VBA - Campare & search through several column in each row

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried to ask program look for a criteria set in D1, then search through each row of col C & col E for the criteria, but error occur. for example criteria put is "Gold,Silver", then the program search for either gold or silver in col C and E respectively in each row, considering i got several row to search. The program works only if range("E:E" & "C:C") is replaced by Range("E:E").

Below is the code:

```
var1 = Range("D1").Value
Dim aString() As String: aString = Split(var1, ",")

For Each cell In Sheets("data").Range("E:E" & "C:C")

    If (Len(cell.Value) = 0) Then Exit For 
    For i = 0 To UBound(aString)        
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, aString(i), vbTextCompare) Then
        Msgbox "found aString's value in col E and col C"
        End if
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
For Each cell In Sheets("data").Range("E:E" & "C:C")
```

to

```
For Each cell In Sheets("data").Range("E:E,C:C")
```

Comment: Tried the changes u suggested, cannot work. i'm using VB 6.5 & Excel 2007.

Comment: @KwaiLum, columns need to be in order `E:E,C:C` will not work, but `C:C,E:E` may. also, the separator character may be `;`, which would mean it would be `C:C;E:E` in that case